# Calculation does not work on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe such as below.

```
df.head()
Out[20]: 
        Date   Price    Open    High  ...       Vol.  Change %  A Day %  OC %
0 2016-04-25  9577.5  9650.0  9685.0  ...   306230.0     -0.83     1.79 -0.75
1 2016-04-26  9660.0  9567.5  9695.0  ...   389490.0      0.86     1.52  0.97
2 2016-04-27  9627.5  9660.0  9682.5  ...   277940.0     -0.34     1.02 -0.34
3 2016-04-28  9595.0  9625.0  9667.5  ...    75120.0     -0.34     1.36 -0.31
4 2016-04-29  9532.5  9567.5  9597.5  ...   138340.0     -0.65     0.73 -0.37
```

I sliced it with some conditions. As a result I got a list of sliced indices `con_down_success` whose length is 96.

Also, I made a list such as,

```
con_down_success_D1 = [x+1 for x in con_down_success]
```

What I want to do is below.

```
df.iloc[con_down_success_D1,:].Low/df.iloc[con_down_success,:].Price
```

This code is supposed to show calculated series but too many are NaNs like below.

```
(df.iloc[con_down_success_D1,:].Low/df.iloc[con_down_success,:].Price).tail(12)
Out[26]: 
778    0.995716
779         NaN
787         NaN
788         NaN
794         NaN
795         NaN
821         NaN
822         NaN
827         NaN
828         NaN
830         NaN
831         NaN
```

All of the two series have actual numbers, not NaN or NA. For example, below is no problem.

```
df.iloc[831,:].Low/df.iloc[830,:].Price
Out[18]: 0.9968354430379747
```

Could you tell me how to handle the dataframe to show what I want?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the last values of `con_down_success` and `con_down_success_D1`?

Comment: This is an index alignment issue. The series don't share the same indices, so you get `NaN` as `pandas` aligns on index for division. Probably better to use `.shift` when defining the numerator.

Comment: @lanThompson  The last value of `con_down_success` is 830 while `con_down_success_D1`'s is 831.

Comment: @ALollz Oh really? It sounds not so handy that I can only use designated index slicing of a dataframe.

Comment: No, it's far more handy that it forces alignment and that you need to go out of your way to deal with misaligned things. Otherwise why not just use `numpy`. That aside, if you need to divide a Series by another with shifted values (which you're doing with the `.iloc[index+1]` this is **exactly** what shift is used for. You want: `df.iloc[con_down_success, :].Low.shift()/df.iloc[con_down_success,:].Price`

Comment: @ALollz Okay. I will use .shift. Thanks!